# Does using execvp concatenate stdin?

Tags: c, linux, shell, stdin, execvp

Does execvp() concatenate stdin, and then execute?

I don't completely understand this command

A classmate of mine is letting me look at his code(a shell that executes in the terminal) to figure the whole thing out,
but I'm not quite understanding why stdin is changed to point to the output of the last child. The only sense I could make out of this is that execvp must concatenate stdin so that we can run out piped command on the previous output. Any insight would be helpful, thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include "ourhdr.h"


extern int makeargv(char *, char * , char ***);
void execfunction(int z, char **args);
int main() // starts main function 
{
    char buffer[80];
    char **myargv;          // The array we put the tokens into
    char delim[] = "|\n";       // delimit the array by this value 
    pid_t pid;
    pid_t currentpid = getpid();    // recognize the master parent process
    int tokey;              // number of tokens
    int x;                  // counter
    int fdl[2];             // piping file descriptors 0 for reading
    int fdr[2];             // and 1 for writing

    printf("Prompt: ");         // start output prompt
    while(getpid() == currentpid && strcmp(fgets(buffer, 80, stdin), "exit\n") != 0)
    {
        tokey = makeargv(buffer, "|\n", &myargv);       // tokenize args into commands
        x = tokey;
        char **myargs;                  
        char delim2[] = " \n";
        int subargument;

        subargument = makeargv(myargv[0], delim2, &myargs);

        if (strcmp(myargv[0], "pwd") == 0) // pwd command
        {
            getcwd(buffer,80);
            write(1,buffer,strlen(buffer));
            write(1, "\n",1);
        }
        else if (strcmp(myargs[0], "cd") == 0) // cd command
        {
            chdir(myargs[1]);
        } 
        else
        {
            pid = fork();
        }
        while(pid == 0 && x > 0) // if child 
        {
            x--;
            if(x == 0) // leftmost 
            {
                pipe(fdr);
                fdr[0] = fdl[0];
                fdr[1] = fdl[1];
                close(fdr[0]);

                char * redir;
                redir = strchr(myargv[0], '<');
                if(redir != NULL)
                {
                    int y;
                    y = open(redir + 1,0x1ff);
                    redir = 0;
                }
                fdr[1] = dup2(fdr[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                execfunction(x,myargv); 
            }
            else if (x == tokey - 1) // rightmost
            {
                pipe(fdl);
                pid = fork();
                if(pid > 0)
                {
                    close(fdl[1]);
                    fdl[0] = dup2(fdl[0], STDIN_FILENO);
                    execfunction(x,myargv);
                }
            }
            else // middle
            {
                pipe(fdr);
                fdr[1] = fdl[1];
                fdr[1] = dup2(fdr[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                fdr[0] = fdl[0];
                pipe(fdl);
                pid = fork();
                if(pid > 0)
                {
                    close(fdl[1]);
                    fdl[0] = dup2(fdl[0], STDIN_FILENO);
                    execfunction(x, myargv);
                }
            }
        }
        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
        if(getpid() == currentpid)
        {
            printf("Prompt: "); // starts prompt output again
        }
    }
}

void execfunction(int z, char **args) // exec method
{
    char **myargs;     
        char delim3[] = " \n";
        int subarguments;
        subarguments = makeargv(args[z], delim3, &myargs); 
    execvp(myargs[0], myargs); // executes here (MAGIC!!!!)

}
```

Comment: Nothing is done on *stdin* by `execvp`. Read [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and [execvp[3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.2.html) and [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: then how does execvp use the output of the child process? for example ls | grep a

Comment: The shell has called [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) before [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). You really need to take several hours to read material.

Comment: I recommend looking inside the source code of [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/). The code you show us is wrong (`pid` may stay uninitialized and used).

Comment: I ask for the help of people because the text/manpages don't quite make it clear to me. Telling me to study harder doesn't help me if I'm only asking SO because the "material" isn't helping me understand.

Comment: The  [fork syscall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29) *is* tricky to understand. Take several hours to read material, notably the *Advanced Linux Programming* book, which has good chapters about it.

Comment: You know Basile, despite me not knowing as much as you and not having that many years of experience. Most of us weren't able to stomach man pages at first without someone predigesting it for us. After a while, we learn that they're very useful and highly nutritious. ;)

Answer (score 3):

So execvp will replace a the currently running process (program) with a new one.

So lets run an example, I skip some of the syntax to use execvp properly

Program A

```
int main(){
    while(1){
        execvp( Program B );
        printf("Hello\n);
    }
}
```

Program B

```
int main(){
    while(1)
        printf("Bye\n");
}
```

So if we start program A, execvp will REPLACE, the currently running program with program B. It doesn't matter that it's in a while(true) loop. Program A no longer exists once it hits the execvp, while the PID will be the same, no trace of Program A is left.
The output will be "bye bye bye ..."

So lets modify Program A to:

```
int main(){
    if( fork() == 0 ){
         execvp( Program B);
    } else {
        while(1){
            printf("Hello\n);
        }
    }
}
```

Fork creates an EXACT clone of the currently running program, and START running IMMEDIATELY. It will return 0 to the CHILD, and it will return an new PID to the PARENT. If you get the PID of the CHILD and compare it to the PID returned by the fork() to the PARENT, you will see that it matches.

So, what does the modified Program A do?
Well, Program A creates a child, which calls execvp on Program B. So the CHILD will REPLACE itself with Program B, and print "Bye" at the SAME time, the parent of Program A, will jump to the else statement and print "Hello".

The terminal output will be a mix of "Hello" and "Bye".

Hope it helps.

Comment: This certainly helps. But what I'm having the most trouble understanding is how something like "ls | grep myfile" would work. to my understanding, in this command, grep will search whatever output ls provides. How does grep know to search within those constraints?

Comment: The shell simply sets up stdout and stdin after forking the child and before executing the grep command in the child just like the code you posted.

Comment: ` fdl[0] = dup2(fdl[0], STDIN_FILENO);` is the magic command that replaces the childs stdandrad inuput with whatever fdl is pointing too.
`pipe` and `dup2` are often used together to pipe of one program into another